# I want to draw diagonal lines to Excel cells with openpyxl module in python

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

When I execute my source, top, bottom, left, and right are applied border_style but the rest are not.
(I wanted to attach it as an image, but I can not fill 10 reputations yet and attach it as a link.)

["when I execute source"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LRr9.jpg)

and This is the result I want

["I expect"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdJ5J.jpg)

I also try to use `diagonalUp=True`, `diagonalDown=True` but It didn't work
I do not know what options I need to set up.

```
from openpyxl.styles import Border, Side
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active

ws['B2'] = "test"
ca2 = ws['B2']

box = Border(left=Side(border_style="thin",color='FF000000'),
                 right=Side(border_style=None,color='FF000000'),
                 top=Side(border_style="double",color='FF000000'),
                 bottom=Side(border_style=None,color='FF000000'),
                 diagonal=Side(border_style="thin",color='FF000000'),
                 diagonal_direction=0,
                 outline=Side(border_style="double",color='FF000000'),
                 vertical=Side(border_style="double",color='FF000000'),
                 horizontal=Side(border_style="double",color='FF000000')
                )
ca2.border = box

wb.save("test.xlsx")
```

The main issue is that I want to know why diagonal does not work. If you can afford it, I would like to know why outline, vertical, and horizontal are not working. Probably my usage is wrong and I guess these things do not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to explicitly set the direction of the diagonal. For top-left to bottom right use `box.diagonalDown=True` and for bottom-left to top-right use `box.diagonalUp=True`.